# How to query for data from database in ruby on rails without using the primary id

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I'm working on Rails 3.2.9 app with ruby 1.9.3 and mysql as my DB . I want to retrieve a particular column data called `'no_of_tc'`from a model named "excel_file' but i dont have the primary key/id of tat row . All i have is the `filename`.

`tc_no = ExcelFile.find(35).no_of_tc` gives me the result but i dont have  id all the time

`tc_no = ExcelFile.find_by filename: 'excel_name`' gives the error **"unknown method - find_by"**

How can i get the required data without having the primary key?? and why am I getting unknown method error for 'find_by'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming :file_name is another attribute of ExcelFile class.

try:

```
tc_no = ExcelFile.find_by_file_name(#name_of_the_fie)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked:):) tc_no = ExcelFile.find_by_file_name(#name_of_the_fie).no_of_tc gave me the data i wanted